# I want to increment employee ID for each object I create to employee class

Tags: .net, c#-3.0

```
 private static int empid = 1;

 public employee()
 {
      empid+=1;
 }
```

But the changes are reflecting in all the created objects.

Any idea about this?

Comment: `"But the changes are reflecting in all the created objects."` - What changes?  What objects?  You have exactly one static variable, and you update that variable every time you create a new instance of the object.  What isn't working?

Comment: What happening is assume i create an object emp1...now the empId must be 2... again i am trying to create emp2 object..the empid is 3...after this even for emp1 the empid is changing to 3

Comment: Instead of "assuming" how about you "demonstrate" the problem?  Where in your objects do you store the calculated value?  If you're not storing the value in your objects and always just referencing the same static value then your objects will always show the current state of that value.  When you add 1 to that value, it increases by 1.

Comment: Now i got it..i was referring the same static variable...thank u so much

Comment: I would also suggest to take out the static variable and pass in some Id generator to the employee class and let that generator increment the id and maintain the latest id.
`public Employee(IIdgenerator idGenerator){ employeeId = idGenerator.Next();}`